# Lightning Component > force:inputField is not working for picklist in Sandbox

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, pre-release

I am working on a lightning component where I want to show picklist field using  as follows. `

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="conObj" type="Contact" default="sobjectType:'Contact'}"/>
    <force:inputField value="{!v.conObj.Salutation}" aura:id="pic"/>    
</aura:component>
```

`

The above code works fine in my developer org but not working on sandbox. When I try to run this by adding in an app throws some exception. Although same component works in same sandbox if I replace inputField with outputField.

Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: what error did you get here?

Comment: Are the orgs on the same version? Some orgs have begun to be upgraded to Spring 16.

Comment: @TusharSharma :  I was able to show this without apex controller in my Dev org. But it does not seems to be working in Sandbox. I am getting following error in popup while previewing this using app. "Something has gone wrong. Aura.loadComponent(): Failed to initialize application. An internal server error has occurred Error ID: 264896843-35663 (1700706397). Please try again." Whereas in console log I can see following warning message: "WARNING: Callback failed: aura://ComponentController/ACTION$getApplication"  It doesn't seems to be working even with an apex controller in sandbox.

Comment: @Peter:  Sandbox is on Spring 16 version.

Comment: Difference in version is important. You should escalate this to support immediately. Whenever there is a problem between GA  and pre-release, support should be your first contact.

Comment: @Peter : This code also runs fine in Developer Org having version Spring 16.

Whereas it doesn't seems to be working on any sandbox on Spring 16.

Comment: Please raise a ticket with support. If the code works...but not in one type of environment, I would always be suspicious of a bug. "Internal Server Error" is always a bug...really...at the very least we should be packaging the error and telling you what is wrong.

Comment: Did you guys had any answers ? I have the same issue, but on different Dev org, one prerelease and one "normal". Could not make it work anywhere, can you ? Maybe it's a Spring'16 bug ? @Peter

Comment: I can confirm not working in my client's sandbox either.  has anyone opened a support ticket?  I cannot since support is telling me "Standard customers get development support through our community".

Comment: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008d7fAAA seems to be related - if not same root cause.  It's In Review, but no idea how long until it's resolved.

Comment: I had code that worked last Friday. Today I get this callback failed message. The errors that lightning throws are horribly vague. No reference to method or function called. Working with lightning so far has been very frustrating because of the horrible error message that it throws

Comment: this is the second time a completely vague error was caused by : (colon) instead of a ; (semi-colon) in a component helper function. In this case giving me same vague call back failed message with no reference at all to what method or piece of code might be causing the problem

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below code.formatted syntax

You have missed curly braces for default attribute

```
<aura:attribute name="conObj" type="Contact" default="{ 'sobjectType' : 'Contact' }"/>
<force:inputField value="{!v.conObj.Salutation}" aura:id="pic"/>
```